# How to reposition the labels in a tableview cell for hidden views?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints, tableview

[image: This is my resulting page. Here instead of using n/a for labels which donot have value, I want to hide them and move the other labels likewise and also adjust the UITableViewCell height likewise. Is there any other way to attain it without connecting the height and top constraint and changing them in runtime? Changing constraint in runtime shows many warnings and doesn't work in every case.]

Here instead of using n/a for labels which don't have value, I want to hide them and move the other labels on top likewise and also adjust the UITableViewCell height likewise. Is there any other way to attain it without connecting the height and top constraint and changing them in runtime? Changing constraint in runtime shows many warnings and doesn't work in every case. Is there a way to do it using autolayout itself?

Comment: Your labels below the text "Jware Consulting Firm" are inside `UITableViewCells`? And what you wish to achieve is not show the fields with "n/a", right?

Comment: yes all of them are inside a uitableview cell. Yes i want to hide the labels instead of showing n/a and i want to reposition other labels likewise and also update the cell size

Comment: Just use `UITableViewAutomaticDimensions` so that cells resize on their own. And well in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` don't add the labels that have "n/a"

Comment: I have been using UITableViewAutomaticDimension because all my labels are multiline.. but even if i dont add the labels with n/a, it will still take its height and top space, no??

Comment: Basically in your array that you are using to set the tableViewCells, remove the objects that have "n/a". Won't that solve the problem? If the "n/a" object isn't in the dataSource array of your `UITableView` that particular cell won't get created. Soo other cells will be made in its place. I don't understand your concern regarding height and top space.

Comment: Then how do I set the constraints in storyboard.. In my storyboard, the labels are set in a way like they are interrelated to each other. for eg: the website label has its top space with respective to email label and so on for other labels as well. I don't want empty space in between. I want the labels to shift upward if empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126445/discussion-between-isha-balla-and-rikh).

Comment: check my answer from the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40189092/swift-dynamic-tableview-in-proportion-to-label-height-filled-with-text/40189314#40189314  this answer will give you dynamic cell size and resize your cell according to your label data..if you want hide your label.and unhide when data loaded to the particular label..u can do this easily by playing with your label alpha....hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered such a problem too and the solution is to programmatically add these labels. I understand the fact that auto-layout makes it easier because of the visual provided to us. But when you have to set the entire table dynamically the way you are asking for, it needs to be done programmatically.

The best way to do is remove the labels and add an UIView taking up the whole space that you need for the labels to occupy. Give left, top, right and bottom constraints. Do not provide with height and width as it would be dynamic depending on the data and device respectively.

Create UIImageView and UILabel in code with proper hard coded CGRect frame and insert these views in the view of the cell for every single data to be display using iteration. This will do the part of inserting your data in the view. The next problem that would come up is the dynamic cell height. In heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method of UITableViewDelegate programmatically count the number of labels you are going to add in the cell and multiple with the height you are giving it in cellForRowAtIndexPath method of UITableViewDataSource. You need to return a CGFloat value in the method heightForRowAtIndexPath so add the above obtained value and the constant values which you have provided in the storyboard(Firm Name, Contact US label and social media bar at the bottom).

Here you would get the display as you desire on your device but in any of the label texts in the UIView to be added in the view are greater than the width of the view itself, they will be truncated till that point. If you want to make this label double line you would ultimately have to increase the cell height as well which would take a whole another method to do as width of the label would vary from device to device. And also the next view u programmatically will overlap the previous double lined label.